# Is p5.js working on codepen?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am testing my p5.js work on codepen but doesnt work.

Can you help why this doesn't work?

[test page](http://nhmk.main.jp/design/highlights)

Comment: Wait you are testing it on codepen but in the title, you ask is it working in fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, wronf title. Moved to code pen and this is direct link : https://codepen.io/mimose/pen/GMZwyL

Comment: Yes, that link is for codepen, how does that prove or demostrate it's not working on JSFiddle, or am I missing the meaning of fiddle?

Comment: Please read [how to correctly ask a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What do you your code expect to do? "Why does this not work?" is not an appropriate question here.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The CodePen link in your comments works fine for me:

[image: CodePen]

The link in your post looks like this:

[image: homepage]

...ah, I see now that there is a CodePen on that page that isn't loading. (You should really try to be more specific about exactly what you're seeing, this is why you're getting downvotes and confused comments.)

To debug that, you need to open the [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) and look at the JavaScript console. You have a bunch of errors there that you need to fix.

Note that the CodePen you link in your page is different from the CodePen you've linked in the comments. The CodePen in the comments ends with `GMZwyL`, but the CodePen in your page ends with `wrWJpg`. If I go to that and look at the JavaScript console I see an error about not being able to load an image, and all I see is a blue screen.

You need to [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and make sure you look at all of the errors being generated.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to link jQuery,,,,this is solved.

Comment: @Mimose If your question is solved, note that you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). More info here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work